# How to replace a word from a file with elements in an array

Tags: arrays, string, bash, replace, str-replace

I am trying to replace all the word "null" to elements in array. The problem is that after replacing one word of "null", I would like to replace the next "null" with next element in the array.

I am not very good with bash and I feel like this is quite a basic question.

Here is what I have so far:

```sh
for m in $(cat finalfile.csv)
do
    if [ "$m" = "null" ]
    then
        m=cwearray[$counter]
        let counter++
    fi
done
```

This doesn't replace anything in the `finalfile.csv`.

For example if the file has:

```
"value1","value2","null","value3"\n
"value1","value2","null","value3"...
```

and the array has ["foo","bar"]

I would like it to be:

```
"value1","value2","foo","value3"\n
"value1","value2","bar","value3"...
```

Comment: Have you changed the field separator?  If not, the file is being split on newline.  Therefore your $m will be the entire line.

Comment: I tried to make it echo "its null" everytime it met with "null" and the number of echo was correct so i think the for loop is finding the "null" value correctly just not changing it to the elements in the array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can be done with bash, even with multiple nulls per line:

```
$ cat finalfile.csv
"value1","value2","null","null"
"value1","value2","null","value3"

$ cwearray=( foo bar baz )

$ idx=0

$ while read -r line; do 
    while [[ $line == *null* ]]; do 
      line=${line/null/${cwearray[idx++]}}
      # ...............^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      # replace the _first_ "null" with the _next_ array element
    done
    echo "$line"
  done < finalfile.csv > updatedfinalfile.csv

$ cat updatedfinalfile.csv
"value1","value2","foo","bar"
"value1","value2","baz","value3"
```

Comment: To replace all `null`s on a line (instead of just the first), can be changed to: `line=${line//null/${cwearray[idx++]}}`

Comment: That will change all the nulls on the line with *the same replacement*, so not what the OP is wanting.

Answer (score 2):

It's easier in Perl where you can increase the index directly in the replacement part of a substitution:

```
printf '%s\n' 1,2,3,null null,2,3,4 null,null,null,null \
| perl -pe 'BEGIN { @cwe = qw( A B C D E F ) }
            s/(?:^|(?<=,))null(?=,|$)/$cwe[$i++]/g'
```

*Update:* It seems you've updated your question with a sample input. If nulls are double quoted, it gets even easier, as there's no need to check whether they're surrounded with commas *or* beginning/end of the line.

```
perl -pe 'BEGIN{ @cwe = qw( foo bar ) }
          s/"null"/"$cwe[$i++]"/g'
```

Comment: I have a doubt.. what happens if two nulls are on same line ?

Comment: @CorentinLimier: Try running the first example, it already contains 4 nulls on the same line.

Comment: Well then I now love perl

Answer (score 0):

Read the file line by line. If a line contains `null`, then use `sed` to replace all occurrences of `null` with the corresponding value, retrieved via array index.

```
#!/bin/bash

file="finalfile.csv"
counter=0

array=(
  "foo"
  "bar"
)

while read -r line; do
  item="${array[$counter]}"
  echo "$line" | sed "s/null/$item/g"
  ((counter++))
done < "$file"
```

Comment: It does not work if there are two null on same line or if some line does not contains null.

Comment: @corentin-limier - it does. Try it for yourself.

Comment: I tried. with `array=("foo" "bar" "foobar")` and finalfile.csv like this : `"null","null"\n"a","b"\n"a","b"\n"null","c"\n`

Comment: It returns `"foo","foo"\n"a","b"\n""a","b"\n"","c"\n` which is not what OP wants

Comment: Should be `"foo","bar"\n"a","b"\n"a","b"\n"foobar","c"\n`

Comment: @corentin-limier - No. Your example is flawed. You give 4 lines in the CSV, yet specify only 3 array items. You must specify at least as many array items as there are CSV lines, given the constraints of OP's question.

Comment: `The problem is that after replacing one word of "null", I would like to replace the next "null" with next element in the array`

Comment: You must specify at least as many array items as there are .. nulls on file - not csv lines

Comment: @corentin-limier - We interpret the question differently then. My solution works, given OP's expected sample output.

Answer (score 0):

An awk solution :

```
declare -a cwearray
cwearray=(foo bar)
awk -F, 'NR==FNR{repl[NR]=$0; next}{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i=="\"null\""){$i="\""repl[++counter]"\""}}}1' OFS="," <(for i in "${cwearray[@]}"; do echo "$i"; done) <file>
```